# Local Nominatim install accessing with API

Tags: ubuntu, nominatim

I have installed a local Nominatim install on Ubuntu using the instructions located at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation and I am using Apache.  The installation appears to function as I can open up the web site, see the map, and query the database and get results.

What I am tying to do is access a local version of the API:
For example:   http://myinstll/search?q=135+pilkington+avenue,+birmingham&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1

Is there an additional package that needs to be installed or additional steps to expose the API?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this specifying the user agent in the request:

```
request.UserAgent = "MyUserAgent";
```